# sum if with some conditions

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Guys here's what I want to do...
I have 3 columns: category, product and quantity. A product can be in more categories... what I want to do is to sum the quantities for each product in each category... I can do SUMIF looking for the product as a criteria but then it will count it no matter the category... do you have any solution? (I don't want to use a pivot because then it will be simple...)
To give you an example let's say we have 3 categories... t-shirts, pants and shoes and 3 brands... let's say one is nike and we have it in all three categories... I want to sum the quantities of nike pants ... the quanties of nike t-shirts and the quantities of nike shoes... if I do a SUMIF with nike as a criteria it will sum everything no matter what they are.
Thanks!

Here's an example:
Let's say we have the following table
[image]
I want the following result
[image]

Comment: could you provide some examples for better understanding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on what you want to be simple.  Like Brett said, a pivot table is the easiest to implement.

Another solution is to use `SUMPRODUCT`.  The below would find the matches for Category A Product 1.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A2:A11="A"),--(B2:B11=1),C2:C11)
```

`SUMPRODUCT` is well outside of easy I'd say.

Answer (score 2):

A basic PivotTable will produce this summary for you

I suggest you see Debra Dalgleigh's site [here](http://www.contextures.com/xlPivot01.html) for the background info - it won't take long to create

[image: Pivot Fields for your output]

Comment: nice link and btw, obviously the easiest and simpliest way to handle this issue